# update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim corrupt: invalid status

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, vim

Whenever I try to install, update, or do anything with apt-get, I always get a error message similar to this, griping about vim:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up vim (2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing vim (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vim
```

Not exactly sure what's going on here. My assumption is that something is corrupt with vim? Here is what I've tried to fix the issue:

1. Uninstall vim (`sudo apt-get remove vim`) - Removing fails and gives back an error similar to the one above.
2. `sudo apt-get purge vim` - Fails, same errors.
3. Removing the `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim` file mentioned in the error message and then trying remove/purge again - Removing/purging still fails, but instead of:

   ```
   update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim corrupt: invalid status
   ```

   In its place, I get:

   ```
   update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vimdiff corrupt: line not terminated while trying to read status
   ```
4. Installing vim again - Fails, same errors.
5. `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove`- Fails, same errors.
6. `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` - Fails, same errors.

This is getting a bit annoying. vim just won't die. What's going wrong? What am ***I*** doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

** **EDIT** **

As requested:

Output of `LC_MESSAGES=C update-alternatives --query vim`:

```
Link: vim
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/vim.basic
Value: /usr/bin/vim.basic

Alternative: /usr/bin/vim.basic
Priority: 30
```

content of `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vimdiff`:

```
b0VIM 7.3Ýroot
```

Can't fetch the content of /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim because I deleted it, haha sorry.

Comment: What's the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim` and the output of `LC_MESSAGES=C update-alternatives --query vim`? Same for `vimdiff`, please.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've edited the question to include the information.

Comment: That file is indeed corrupted. Here's what mine looks like: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14264045/

Comment: @muru Ick, thats not right at all, haha! Yeah, it raised a red flag as soon as I saw the output. Thanks for the comparison. I just copied in the contents of your file into mine. New errors:
`/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vimdiff corrupt: unexpected end of file while trying to read master file`

`/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/rvim corrupt: line not terminated while trying to read status`

Comment: @MD-7 I'm not sure copying mine was the best idea - you don't have `vim.gnome`, for one.  For another, the paste doesn't show it, but the file has an extra, blank line at the end (one more line after `60`).

Comment: @muru True. It was worth a shot, at least. But its beginning to look there's a lot of files that are corrupted. Surely there's some way to nuke vim off my system. It seems counter-intuitive that the system wouldn't let you remove a corrupted program.

Comment: Well, it's not Vim that's corrupted, it's the package manager's information of vim packages. :P Anyway, if you look at my file and the output of `-update-alternatives`, you might see a pattern. (And remember the extra blank line at the end.)

Comment: @muru Ahh, right, right, thanks. That file's fixed. But do I really have to just keep going in and manually fixing all these files? File x is corrupted > search on internet for a sample of that file > extrapolate a proper file for my sytem; File y is corrupted > search on internet for a sample of that file > extrapolate a proper file for my sytem >>... Is this really the solution?

Comment: I don't know about that. This is the first time I'm seeing such a corruption. When the problem gets rare enough, it's likely there are no built-in mechanisms to help. You could file a bug report, and perhaps devs could help you find what caused this.

Comment: @muru UGH. Double ick. Alright, at least I have enough information to go from here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternatives entries are hopelessly broken.

1. You should remove them with:

   ```sh
   sudo update-alternatives --remove-all vim
   sudo rm -f /etc/alternatives/vim /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim
   ```

   If `update-alternatives` complains about corrupt files again, ignore it and just proceed to delete them with the next command.
2. Then re-install their packages with:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim
   ```

   This will restore the alternatives entries according to the packages available on your system.
3. Proceed analogously for `vimdiff`, `rvim` and other corrupted entries.

Comment: This sounds promising. It's worked for the first couple files. But now I run `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all rvim` and I get this error message:
`update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/rvim corrupt: line not terminated while trying to read status`. It sounds like it hates the file format (It is corrupted, crazy characters everywhere). Am I back to finding example files online?

Comment: “If `update-alternatives` complains about corrupt files again, ignore it and just proceed to delete them with the next command.”

Comment: PHEW! `rvim` was the last one. That could have been a lot worse. Sorry for skipping over that bit that you had to quote for me haha. Purged then reinstalled. Problem solved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem on one of my servers: `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vtrgb` corrupt

Likely from a failed install and unscheduled reboot during power outage.  I fixed this by just copying the file from another server then doing:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this fixed the broken dpkg and I was able to move on with my life!