# Errors encountering while processing

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, dependencies

I understand this questions has been asked several times, but none of the suggested fixes helped me. I will provide the output of some of the process I tried running.

I would love help with this issue. I had help from friends but they were not able to solve this and I already spent way over 4h on this. I would very much appreciate help.

I am getting this error for the following packages:
 * libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
 * libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

There is some evidence they are dependency errors but I did not make progress in this direction. My idea is that I have packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
and this could cause issues but I am clueless.

I tried to post a lot of things that might help someone help me, but do ask if further information is needed.

(Background) My Lenovo Legion Y520 operates ubuntu 16.04 for months (since I bought it). Three days ago, it ran out of battery. Yesterday, when I charged it, it simply would not turn on normally. I started recovery mode and could only access it through terminal as I got stuck in a login issue loop. It took me sometime but I got the graphics drivers and everything (but this issue) is back to normal. During the process I noticed this problem. I am 100% sure it was not the case before it ran out of battery. This is the first time I get this error.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839202/dpkg-error-processing-package-libgl1-mesa-glxi386-configure)

dpkg --audit

```
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 Texture compression library for Mesa
```

apt-get update: works fine

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Fetched 323 kB in 1s (212 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
```

apt-get clean: works fine (no output)

apt-get upgrade: fails

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 (0~git20131104-1.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/libtxc-dxtn-i386-linux-gnu corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-get -f install: fails

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 (0~git20131104-1.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/libtxc-dxtn-i386-linux-gnu corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

dpkg --configure -a: succeeds (no output)

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/839209/875622)

As for fixes of this sort, my case is with different packages and two packages, so I tried adapting the answers:

`dpkg --force-depends --purge libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`: fails

```
    (Reading database ... 364702 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

`dpkg --force-depends --purge libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`: fails

```
(Reading database ... 364702 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

dpkg --configure libgl1-mesa-glx:i386: fails

```
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I am posting the answer but if requested I can delete the question instead - as I am new and do not know the proper way to do so.

It was a problem with the alternatives (as seen in the warnings). Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714659/update-alternatives-error-var-lib-dpkg-alternatives-vim-corrupt-invalid-stat) I was able to get rid of the error.

Steps for me:
`update-alternatives --remove-all libtxc-dxtn-i386-linux-gnu`
`rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/libtxc-dxtn-i386-linux-gnu`

`update-alternatives --remove-all i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf`
`rm -f /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf`

After that I ran
`apt-get -f install`, which worked for the first time

`apt-get update` is failing but I can investigate that...

Comment: update is back to normal. Upgrade is also working. I think it completely resolved the issue.